# MAMP Pro for multiple wordpress installations connection error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, mamp-pro

**Summary**

I am using MAMP Pro for maintaining local copy of my wordpress website. I am trying to have a separate wordpress installation, and it is giving a database connection error.

**Details**

I'm trying to define multiple hosts in MAMP Pro for separate wordpress installations. The default "localhost" works fine, but if I try to add another host, it doesn't work properly.

Using the new host (wordpress.dev), the browser properly launches the wordpress installation page defined in the (wordpress.dev) directory, but after inserting the database name and credentials, it gives a connection error.

I've double checked the database name, username, password etc. I've also tried to run it using mysql root credentials. I've also given all global rights to the database user, database specific rights etc.  But to no avail.

Since I've been using the default rights for the Document root in MAMP pro, I suspected that it could be a rights issue, I tried to assign all the rights to the System Administrator account or www but nothing worked.

If I press the "Web Start" button on Mamp Pro, the browser opens the following page (http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English) that describes Host as localhost.

**The complete error states as**

> Error establishing a database connection
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
>   wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can't contact the database
>   server at wordpress.dev. This could mean your host's database server
>   is down.
>
> Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
>  Are you
>   sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
>  Are you sure that
>   the database server is running?
>
> If you're unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact
>   your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress
>   Support Forums.

Please keep in mind that the host "wordpress.dev" is present, and when I point it in the browser, it loads the defined directory but it is unable to connect to the database using that server.

I tested to remove the password from the database user and the error changes to this.

> Can’t select database
>
> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the mydb database.
>
> Are you sure it exists?
>     Does the user myadmin have permission to use the mydb database?
>     On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_mydb. Could that be the problem?
>
> If you don't know how to set up a database you should contact your host. If all else fails you may find help at the WordPress Support Forums.

Thanks for reading my question and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your wp-config ? and any specific problem about it..

Comment: Of course, remove sensitive information from the wp-config file before you paste it here.

Comment: It is in the installation phase, only wp-config-sample.php exist with my db, username, password and host information. http://pastebin.com/1rjBBCSk

Comment: do you have write permissions to the folder to generate the true wp-config?

Comment: The website is in a regular directory and there shouldn't be any problem for write permissions. I have tried giving all rights to the dbuser as well as rights specific to that database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting much time, I came to know that I was forgetting to rename the configuration file from wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php.

Although wordpress installation was asking the details to generate the configuration file but probably, the wordpress installation didn't have the permissions to generate any file on my system.

Answer (score 0):

I use MAMP + Mac OS

It works with these settings in wp-config.php

```
define('DB_NAME', 'your name_db');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost:8889');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```